# EventSourcing with NServiceBus Subscribe to all Events

Tags: c#, events, nservicebus

I want use NServiceBus with GetEventStore to create CQRS/EventSourcing solution.

I have a set of Events each is stamped with Aggregate type name and Aggregate id. My domain publishes events using NServiceBus. All events derive from one base type.

I want create message handler which subscribes to all events published by domain, so it can save events in EventStore.

I tried subscribe to my base Event but it doesn't work.

Is there any way to subscribe to all types of events? I don't also want to change NServiceBus configuration or add new handler in my EventStore worker each time I create new domain Event.

Comment: What version are you on?(we've fixed a few bugs related to subscribing to base classes recently)

Comment: @AndreasÖhlund I used 4.2.0, I will try 4.3.0 later and I will update you.

Comment: @AndreasÖhlund the problem was lying in my configuration. I didn't realize that EndpointConfig's namespace influence configuration.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've managed to solve the problem. I have a base Event class and I publish events that derive from the base Event class. On my subscriber I subscribe to base Event and Handle method is firing every time derived event is published.

## Messages project

```
public class Event : IEvent
{
}
public class Event1 : Event
{
}
public class Event2 : Event
{
}
```

## Publisher project

### Publishers EndpointConfig

```
namespace SemplePublisherNamespace
{
    using NServiceBus;
    public class EndpointConfig : IConfigureThisEndpoint, AsA_Publisher
    {

    }
}
```

### Publishers OnBusStart class

```
public class OnBusStart : IWantToRunWhenBusStartsAndStops
{
    public IBus Bus { get; set; }
    void IWantToRunWhenBusStartsAndStops.Start()
    {
        Bus.Publish(new Event1());
        Bus.Publish(new Event2());
    }

    void IWantToRunWhenBusStartsAndStops.Stop()
    {
    }
}
```

### Publishers app.config

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" standalone="yes"?>
<configuration>
  <configSections>
    <section name="MessageForwardingInCaseOfFaultConfig" type="NServiceBus.Config.MessageForwardingInCaseOfFaultConfig, NServiceBus.Core" />
    <section name="AuditConfig" type="NServiceBus.Config.AuditConfig, NServiceBus.Core"/>
  </configSections>
  <MessageForwardingInCaseOfFaultConfig ErrorQueue="error"/>
  <AuditConfig QueueName="audit" />
</configuration>
```

## Subscriber project

### Subscribers EndpointConfig

```
namespace SampleSubscriber
{
    using NServiceBus;

    public class EndpointConfig : IConfigureThisEndpoint, AsA_Server
    {
    }
}
```

## Subscribers app.config

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" standalone="yes"?>
<configuration>
  <configSections>
    <section name="MessageForwardingInCaseOfFaultConfig" type="NServiceBus.Config.MessageForwardingInCaseOfFaultConfig, NServiceBus.Core" />
    <section name="UnicastBusConfig" type="NServiceBus.Config.UnicastBusConfig, NServiceBus.Core" />
    <section name="AuditConfig" type="NServiceBus.Config.AuditConfig, NServiceBus.Core" />
  </configSections>
  <MessageForwardingInCaseOfFaultConfig ErrorQueue="error" />
  <UnicastBusConfig>
    <MessageEndpointMappings>
      <add Assembly="Messages" Endpoint="SemplePublisherNamespace" />      
    </MessageEndpointMappings>
  </UnicastBusConfig>
  <AuditConfig QueueName="audit" />
</configuration>
```

Note that in MessageEndpointMappings secion when adding mapping we set Endpoint name and it's the same as namespace of EndpontConfig class in Publisher project.

### Subscriber's Handler class

```
    public class Subscriber : IHandleMessages<Event>
    {
        public void Handle(Event message)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Handle: "+message.GetType().Name);
        }

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Another possible approach would be to have your `Event` acting as a generic envelope with the actual content inside:

```
public class GenericEnvelope
{
    ...
    public XmlElement Message { get; set; }
}
```

This still lets you subscribe once and then pass whatever the content you want but the advantage of such approach is that the envelope could possibly contain some message-oriented attributes that **are not** part of the message. Another advantage is that passing the content as `XmlElement` lets you implement your own message-level security/integrity (signing and/or encryption).

Comment: I don't want build messaging middleware on top of NServiceBus since NServiceBus is middleware on top of messaging system. If NServiceBus doesn't provide me all the features I need I will simply won't use it. If I'm forced to send my events in custom envelop and implement my own message level security then I can build my own infrastructure around MSMQ or RabbitMQ.